# Loop through array of objects and print html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Given a list of URLs and text, I want to print out links for each of them.

Is this set up correctly? I'm getting some strange errors (e.g. printing out the 2nd element 3 times).

```
<%

nav_links = [{
 text: "hello",
 href: "/hello.html"
},
{
 text: "bye",
 href: "/bye.html"
},
{
 text: "whatever",
 href: "/whatever.html"
}]

%>
```

Print the nav links.

```
<% nav_links.each do |nav_link| %>
  <%= link_to nav_link['text'], nav_link['href'] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you mean `nav_links.each do`?

Comment: Can you show us what errors you get?

Comment: try `<%= link_to nav_link[:text], nav_link[:href] %>`

Answer (score 0):

Your keys are symbols, not strings. It should be `nav_link[:text]` and `nav_link[:href]`

Comment: Thanks kdeisz, I'm trying this now: `<%= nav_link[:text] %>` but get an error `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `nav_link['text']` is not the same thing as `nav_link[:text]`.

If you want to use text you need to say `nav_link['text'.to_sym]`

`'text'` is a string
`:text` is a symbol

Comment: Thanks John, I'm trying this now: `<%= nav_link[:text] %>` but get an error `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`. Any ideas?

Comment: @DonnyP Are you sure your not doing `nav_links[:text]` instead of `nav_link[:text]`?